# Can't import binay h2o model with h2o.loadModel() function: 412 Precondition Failed

Tags: r, load, h2o

I've been working with h2o and h2o Flow for the past days and have loved it. Two days ago I exported some models (in binary format) from h2o Flow and imported them with R so I could do further studies. It worked perfectly until today. For some reason, I'm getting the following error when I try the `h2o.loadModel` function (which worked just fine before with all my exported binary models). Just to clarify, I already ran successfully the `h2o.init()` command to open the H2O cluster.

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 412 Precondition Failed (url = http://localhost:54321/99/Models.bin/)

water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException
 [1] "water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Illegal argument: dir of function: importModel: H2O/H2O-XX/gbm_grid1_m02"
 [2] "    water.api.ModelsHandler.importModel(ModelsHandler.java:220)"                                                       
 [3] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"                                                       
 [4] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"                                     
 [5] "    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"                             
 [6] "    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"                                                                  
 [7] "    water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:63)"                                                                         
 [8] "    water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:446)"                                                             
 [9] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:296)"                                                         
[10] "    water.api.RequestServer.doPost(RequestServer.java:222)"                                                            
[11] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)"                                                      
[12] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"                                                      
[13] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"                                            
[14] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)"                                        
[15] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)"                                
[16] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)"                                         
[17] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)"                                 
[18] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)"                                     
[19] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                             
[20] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                                   
[21] "    water.JettyHTTPD$LoginHandler.handle(JettyHTTPD.java:189)"                                                         
[22] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                             
[23] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                                   
[24] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)"                                                           
[25] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)"                    
[26] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)"                     
[27] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)"                          
[28] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)"          
[29] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)"                                                  
[30] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)"                                             
[31] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)"                            
[32] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)"                      
[33] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)"                                  
[34] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)"                                   
[35] "    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"                                                                             

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 


ERROR MESSAGE:

Illegal argument: dir of function: importModel: H2O/H2O-XX/gbm_grid1_m02
```

Im using the latest h2o version, 3.15.0.4029, on RStudio, macOS Sierra (10.12.6 (16G29))

**UPDATE:** as requested by Erin, posting how I tried to import the model:

```
library(h2o)
#h2o.init(nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = "7G") # Already initiated 
#h2o.removeAll()   
h2oXX <- h2o.loadModel("H2O-XX/GBM_grid_0_AutoML_20171102_095446_model_41")
```

Downgraded to the latest stable version (h2o-3.14.0.7) and receiving the same error: `Illegal argument: dir of function: importModel: H2O-XX/GBM_grid_0_AutoML_20171102_095446_model_41`

Attached model (you can try to import it): bit.ly/h2odemo

Comment: You should always use the latest *stable* version of H2O, not the nightly releases (3.15.0.4029 is a random nightly release).  Download stable here: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable.html Binary models are not compatible between releases, so if you upgraded H2O between when you created the models and now, that will cause a problem.  Can you also update your post with the R code you used to load the model?

Comment: Thanks @ErinLeDell for you reply. Updated the post with the import code and downgrading to the latest stable version. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: unfortunately, you will need to re-train the model using 3.14.0.7 and then try to import it (also using 3.14.0.7).  I think this should resolve the error.

Comment: Yes @ErinLeDell just did that and didn't work out!! Re trained a whole new model and tried to import it (3.14.0.7 of course) and nothing.. same error! I really appreciate your help; any further ideas?

Comment: @ErinLeDell Added a file where you can access the binary file so you can try to import it and check the error: bit.ly/h2odemo

Comment: FIXED: it was as simple as running h2o.shutdown() and then trying again with a new h2o.init() connection!! Thanks @ErinLeDell hope this issue and solution help others

Comment: Glad that worked.  It might be that you were accidentally connecting to the old version of the server.  Even if you have installed a new version of the h2o R package, if there is an old H2O cluster still running, then `h2o.init()` will reconnect to that one instead of starting a new one (using the new version of H2O).  Best to always shut down and restart the cluster when you upgrade your h2o R or Python package.

Comment: I just summarized our conversation as an answer below.  Please accept the answer if you think it's useful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see an error that looks like this (key identifier being this statement `Illegal argument: dir of function: importModel:`)

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 412 Precondition Failed (url = http://localhost:54321/99/Models.bin/)

water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException
[1] "water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Illegal argument: dir of function: importModel: H2O/H2O-XX/gbm_grid1_m02"
```

Then that probably means that you used a different version of H2O to train and save the model than you are using to load the H2O model.  This is a problem because [binary models](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html) (models saved using the `h2o.saveModel()` function) are not compatible between different versions of H2O.

The simple solution is to use the same version of H2O to save and re-load the model.

An alternative solution is to use the [POJO or MOJO](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html#about-pojos-and-mojos) type H2O models. This format for models exports the model as plain Java code and is not tied to a particular version of H2O.  It also does not require the H2O cluster to be running when you generate predictions on test data.  This is typically what you'd want to use if you were to take your H2O models to production.

Comment: Is there a way of identifying which version of H2O was used to build the model? I am getting the same error. But without loading them (or even after loading them in R environment) I don't know which version of H2o model was used to build this model.

Comment: Yes, this information is available in the binary export file. It is in the header of the file in plain text. If you are on Mac/Linux you can type this command to get the version: `strings model.hex | head -1` (where model.hex is the binary export)

Comment: @ErinLeDell I am having the same issue but using the same versions, any ideas?

Comment: @Lucif3r - as mentioned above. just use h2o.shutdown() and then run h2o.init() again. Post that load the model. It should work!