# Is there a preferred method of saving and loading h2o word2vec models in python?

Tags: python, word2vec, h2o

I have trained a word2vec model in the python h2o package.
Is there a simple way for me to save that word2vec model and load it back later for use?

I have tried the h2o.save_model() and h2o.load_model() functions with no luck.
I get an error using that approach like

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 412 Precondition Failed (url = http://localhost:54321/99/Models.bin/)

water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException
[1] "water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Illegal argument: dir of function: importModel:
```

I am using the same version of h2o to train and load the model back in so the issue outlined in this question is not applicable [Can't import binay h2o model with h2o.loadModel() function: 412 Precondition Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062207/cant-import-binay-h2o-model-with-h2o-loadmodel-function-412-precondition-fai)

Any one with any insights on how to save and load an h2o word2vec model?

My sample code with a few of the important snippets

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators import H2OWord2vecEstimator

df['text'] = df['text'].ascharacter()
  
# Break text into sequence of words
words = tokenize(df["text"])
    
# Initializing h2o
print('Initializing h2o.')
h2o.init(ip=h2o_ip, port=h2o_port, min_mem_size=h2o_min_memory) 
   
# Build word2vec model:
w2v_model = H2OWord2vecEstimator(sent_sample_rate = 0.0, epochs = 10)
w2v_model.train(training_frame=words)
    
    
# Calculate a vector for each row
word_vecs = w2v_model.transform(words, aggregate_method = "AVERAGE")

#Save model to path
wv_path = '/models/wordvec/'
model_path = h2o.save_model(model = w2v_model, path= wv_path ,force=True)

# Load model in later script
w2v_model = h2o.load_model(model_path)
```

Comment: What exact code did you try, to get that error? Are both save and load failing with the same error?

Comment: @gojomo Just added the sample code. Only the load fails with that error.                 It might be that I cant save a word2vec model the same way as a machine learning model eg Gradient Boosting model and maybe I can only save the word vector pairings in a .txt file?

Comment: What is the full error, with full stack, you're getting with the shown code? (Because the error you are showing includes a local URL, `http://localhost:54321/99/Models.bin/`, that's suspiciously not otherwise shown in your code.) Also, are you sure that `save_model()` method wants the directory-path you're providing `'/models/wordvec/'`rather than a file-path?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have an access issue with the directory you trying to read from. I just tested on H2O 3.30.0.1 following the [w2v example from docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/word2vec.html#examples) and it ran fine:

```
job_titles = h2o.import_file(("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/craigslistJobTitles.csv"),
                              col_names = ["category", "jobtitle"],
                              col_types = ["string", "string"],
                              header = 1)
STOP_WORDS = ["ax","i","you","edu","s","t","m","subject","can",
              "lines","re","what","there","all","we","one","the",
              "a","an","of","or","in","for","by","on","but","is",
              "in","a","not","with","as","was","if","they","are",
              "this","and","it","have","from","at","my","be","by",
              "not","that","to","from","com","org","like","likes",
              "so"]

# Make the 'tokenize' function:
def tokenize(sentences, stop_word = STOP_WORDS):
    tokenized = sentences.tokenize("\\W+")
    tokenized_lower = tokenized.tolower()
    tokenized_filtered = tokenized_lower[(tokenized_lower.nchar() >= 2) | (tokenized_lower.isna()),:]
    tokenized_words = tokenized_filtered[tokenized_filtered.grep("[0-9]",invert=True,output_logical=True),:]
    tokenized_words = tokenized_words[(tokenized_words.isna()) | (~ tokenized_words.isin(STOP_WORDS)),:]
    return tokenized_words

# Break job titles into a sequence of words:
words = tokenize(job_titles["jobtitle"])

# Build word2vec model:
w2v_model = H2OWord2vecEstimator(sent_sample_rate = 0.0, epochs = 10)

w2v_model.train(training_frame=words)

#Save model
wv_path = 'models/'
model_path = h2o.save_model(model = w2v_model, path= wv_path ,force=True)

#Load Model
w2v_model2 = h2o.load_model(model_path)
```